# diffForHumans() not working on db Facades

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Hello guys i want to show date into diffForHumans()

in my threadcontroller i used

```
$thread = DB::table('threads')
     ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
     ->select('users.*', 'threads.*')
     ->orderBy('threads.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();  return view('thread.index', compact('thread'));
```

and in my view

```
{{ $item->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

but I found error

```
Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string
```

Before that i used `$thread = Thread::paginate(3);` and method diffForHumans() work 
whats my problem??

Comment: I found solution . only add {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} in my blade. It works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel `DB` Facade does not return eloquent objects, therefore, `created_at` and `updated_at` are not of type `DateTime`. Eloquent object datetime instance return an instance of Carbon.

**Solution**

Because your `created_at` comes as a string, you will have to parse it for Carbon to work.

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```